# Vue.js dynamic transition between multiple routes

Tags: css, vue.js, animation, transition, vue-cli

## Description

I'm using Vue-CLI and Vue-route to build up my projects. According to the references, the dynamic transition is working between pages and my logs show correct pathes and transition names between switing routes. I can see the transition classes been set to the DOMs because I tell them to run in 5 seconds.

However, when the route is 
from **place/:place/image1** to **place/:place** and then 
from **place/:place** back to **/** again, 
even the transitionName in logs are correct, and  
**fade** is set from **place/:place/image1** to **place/:place** correctly,
but there is nothing from **place/:place** back to **/**.

The page is just been switched without setting classes to DOMs.
It seems only happen on children routes
Please assist me to figure it out.

---

Here is my routes

```
- /
 |_ place/:place
 |_ place/:place/image1

- /setting
- /menu
```

and route watcher,

```js
 watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
        if (from.path === "/" && to.path.includes("/place")) {
            this.transitionName = "v-slide-up";
        } else if (from.path.includes("/place") && to.path === "/") {
            this.transitionName = "v-slide-up";
        }

        if (to.path === "/setting") this.transitionName = "v-slide-right";

        if (from.path.includes("/place") && to.path.includes("/image1")) {
            this.transitionName = "v-slide-up";
        } else if (from.path.includes("/image1") && to.path.includes("/place")) {
            this.transitionName = "fade";
        }

        console.log(`path from ${from.path} to ${to.path}`);
        console.log(`transition: ${this.transitionName}`);
    }
}
```

and transitions below

```css
.v-slide-up-enter-active,
.v-slide-up-leave-active {
    transition: transform 5s ease;
}
.v-slide-up-enter,
.v-slide-up-leave-to {
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
.v-slide-up-enter-to,
.v-slide-up-leave {
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 5s;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 1;
}

.fade-enter-to,
.fade-leave {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

### References

- https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html#per-route-transition
- https://css-tricks.com/the-power-of-named-transitions-in-vue/

Comment: so you mean when you go from place/:place back to /., does it use fade animation, or there is no animation at all

Comment: @NgocTuanLam no animation at all

Comment: I seem to cannot reproduce the bug, you can refer to this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-taussig-q1rg2?file=/src/App.vue and see if its the same with your setting, moving from  place/:place back to /. seems correct

Comment: Thank you so much,it seems the fade transition is not triggered in your example.

Comment: @JakeLam is it possible related to the route architecture? 
it cannot work if I use this one

    path: "/",
    component: Home,
    children: [
      {
        path: "place/:place",
        component: Place
      },
      {
        path: "place/:place/image1",
        component: PlaceImage
      }
    ]